# Compilation Error when accessing attribute from a class

Tags: java

```
import java.lang.*;
public class BankAccount{
public int _accnum;
public double _accbal;

public BankAccount(){
}

public BankAccount(int num, double bal){
_accnum=num;
_accbal=bal;
}

public double getBal(){
return _accbal;
}
public int getNum(){
return _accnum;
}
public void main(String args[]){
BankAccount bank1=new BankAccount(101,1000);

System.out.println(bank1._accnum);
}
}
```

Hi guys, I am trying to learn Java and I tried creating this object called BankAccount with several simple attributes. I tried to compile and run but I got compilation error. Anyone has any idea why? My knowledge in Java is pretty limited and I would appreciate if someone can explain it in not-so-advanced terms. Thank you!

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at   edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:27 2)
```

> 

Comment: Please post your error message as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing keyword `static` in main method add it like this:

```
  public static void main(String args[]) {...
```

Answer (score 0):

Main method must be static

```
public static void main(String args[]){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `static` Keyword in main method so you need to write like this,

```
public static void main(String args[]) {...
```

Each word has different meaning and different purpose,

**Static :** Keyword which identifies the class related this. It means that this class is not instance related but class related. It can be accessed without creating the instance of Class.

Java compiler always look for main method to compile the source code but here is you didn't provide `static` so compiler is unable to reach main method and trowing compile time error which is `java.lang.NullPointerException`